# Using Regex inside a textarea in Angular template driven form

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angular, typescript

I have a list

```
  list = [
    "Nrvana",
    "Red Hot Chilli Peppers",
    "R.E.M",
    "Reef"
  ]
```

and on the html I am rendering the contents of this list.

```
<div *ngFor= "let x of list" > {{x}}
</div>
<hr/>

<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

I also have a textArea , where a user can write anything he/she wants. Here is the tricky part and something I am unable to figure out. If a user uses syntax `<<userText>>` , a validation error should pop up stating `Please use text from list inside <<>>`. I can do this part but I can't figure out if I need to make a regex and if yes, please help me with it. Please ask if you need any more information.

p.s this is just something I created to get an idea of my problem, the actual project is a very long one and I am using **template-driven forms** 
Here is a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t4cfqc

Comment: Does [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqpbqv) answer your question? (Although it does use *reactive based forms*. Any specific reason for choosing a template driven form?)

Comment: I was told to use template-forms, cause my managers are a bunch of ill-planned people. They told there wont be any validation required. Anyways, the stackbltz solution works for the list but if I try to type anything else, it will give an error. For example   :  "<<R.E.M>> is the best band" will also show the validation error

Comment: Can you provide examples of valid and invalid inputs? I was under the impression that only text *within* <<>> is valid.

Comment: sure. I am editing a stackblitz for it.

Comment: I don't see anything. There are many errors in the code. Could you just give some examples in the comments?

Comment: @NicholasK <https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6a2krd> I hope this link works. I was unable to save the changes in the previous one

Comment: Hmm.. you'll need to write some sort of directive to achieve that.

Comment: @NicholasK any article or something I can refer to?

Comment: After a *basic* google search, [this](https://medium.com/@svsh227/create-a-custom-directive-in-angular-2-application-c1e8ccec9bfa) and [this](https://alligator.io/angular/building-custom-directives-angular/) are good starting points.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you want to accomplish this and what you are exactly trying to do but you could do something like this

**HTML**

```html
<textarea [(ngModel)]="textAreaText" [(ngModelChange)]="checkText()"></textarea>
```

**.TS**

```js
textAreaText: string;

// ...

checkText() {
  const regex = /(?:^|\s)<<(.*?)>>(?:\s|$)/g;

  // If you only want to use certain keywords you could do something like this
  const regex = /(?:^|\s)<<((keyword1)|(keyword2)|(keyword3))>>(?:\s|$)/g;

  if (regex.test(this.textAreaText)) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of that "g" at the end of the regex

Comment: it means `global` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Comment: is there a way for me to replace .*? with names from a list. I have a list with 7 items and only those names can be added between the "<<>>"

Comment: @MenimE please see my updated answer - and dont forget to mark it as correct if this has helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **pattern** attribute too. Example below

```
<textarea pattern="/(?:^|\s)<<(.*?)>>(?:\s|$)/g" [(ngModel)]="myTextArea" #myTextAreaModel="ngModel" required></textarea>

<div *ngIf="myTextAreaModel.errors.pattern">Your error msg here</div>
```